# Extract Html Contents in a Certain Tag without the Outer Tag in PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument, html

I'd like to retrieve html code in a certain tag. I know DomDocument enables to do it. However, If I want to extract the contents without the outer tag, how can it be achieved?

For example,

```
$html = '<div><span>Hello world!</span><br><p>some other text</p></div>';    
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo $doc->saveXML($doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0));
```

this will output,

```
<div>
    <span>Hello world!</span>
    <br>
    <p>some other text</p>
</div>
```

I want it without the outer div tag. I tried the node value but it strips all the tags.

```
$html = '<div><span>Hello world!</span><br><p>some other text</p></div>';    
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
echo $node->nodeValue;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't really make sense, you ask for the tag and its contents but then you say you don't want the tag. Since you know what tag you are asking for, you could remove it quite simply with regex, or you could just simply select the tags you DO want and don't mind having the outer tags of.

Comment: You got the question correctly. That means the question makes sense. If you think it's simple, can you post a solution?

Comment: I agree it makes sense, sometimes I forget myself. I've posted a solution that should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, how about a PHP innerHTML implementation:

```
<?php 
$html = '<div><span>Hello world!</span><br><p>some other text</p></div>';    
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
echo DOMinnerHTML($node);

function DOMinnerHTML($element) 
{ 
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children = $element->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
        $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
        $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
    } 
    return $innerHTML; 
} 
?>
```